How to compare two PMF generating functions?
I have two functions $f$ and $g$ that map an input vector $x_i$ to a probability mass function.
For example:
$$ 
x_i = [0,1,2]  \\\\
f(x_i) \rightarrow [0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2] \\\\
g(x_i) \rightarrow [0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.2] \\\\
$$
There are more than 10,000 input vectors, and the generated PMFs contain up to 1,000 elements.
How to test whether $f$ and $g$ are significantly different from each other?
My thoughts are to use JS-divergence or another similar metric to compare each pair of PMFs given $x_i$, and then take the average of those JS-divergences.
But is there a better way? A more principled way of doing this. I feel that some information is lost by taking an average.
Note that I cannot use a mixture model as the PMFs are paired. In essence I have a set of pairs of PMFs, and I want to test whether the pairs are different from each other.
My application is comparing the outputs from two models $f$ and $g$ given each test sample $x_i$.
edit from comments below:
The models change their output based on how they are defined. For example, model $f$ is defined as $f(x)=\max(xW,0)$
where $W$ are the model parameters, while model $g$
is defined as $g(x)=\max(\max(xW_0,0)W_1,0)$
. Now the question is did this change in the model definition make a difference or not?
The difficulty comes from the randomness in the training process, so two identical models, will have different model parameters given the random seed that was used when fitting the model parameters as they are fit via stochastic gradient descent.
So, training the same model but with different random seeds will give multiple models, each with slightly different output. The pair-wise differences between these different outputs can serve as a null distribution. Then, we can compare this null distribution with the distribution of the differences between the two models we are interested in comparing. Assume the two distributions (of differences) are Gaussian, and do a simple Z-test.
Is this valid and is there a better approach?
after bounty:
It turns out the problem is more complex than I thought. I need to make the problem clearer and think if all this complexity is justified. With that said, this is what I did:

Obtain probabilities from three models:
a. Baseline model, $f$
b. Null model, $f^*$ (same as the baseline model but trained with a different random seed, so the difference between Null and Baseline is solely due to random chance)
c. Alternative model $g$

For each $x_i$ in the test set $T$, calculate the sets of Jensen-Shannon divergences between all models' probabilities, i.e.:
a. $ N = \{ JS(f(x_i), f^*(x_i)) | x_i \in T\}$
b. $ B = \{ JS(f(x_i), g(x_i)) | x_i \in T\}$

Plot the KDE histograms of the sets $N$ and $B$ for visual comparison.


As @whuber implied, the histograms do not look Gaussian. With two big peaks around 0 and some constant which is the result when the probabilities differ at most one element.
Below is the plot between two "good models" (obtaining 98% accuracy) but differently defined, and between a really bad model (obtaining 11% accuracy). The KDE lines of the two good models are essentially the same, and only for obviously different model do the KDE plot differs. Perhaps this is correct and says that there is no difference between the two good models, but I am not completely happy with the results.


Your question cannot be answered because you haven't mentioned any mechanism for these PMFs to vary from what they are.  One would guess that they are not PMFs but are summarizing the frequencies of observations of something.  In that case, your question is still unanswerable because it is critical to know the original counts.  Please, then, tell what data you really have.

Thank you for your comment. The PMFs are outputs from the two models. Maybe PMF is not a good word for it, but it is the estimated probability for the test sample i to belong to each one of the thousand classes. So each "PMF" is a vector, where each vector element k represents the estimated probability that the sample $x_i$ belongs to the class k. Let me know if I should change the wording PMF to something else. I don't know how to call it, but it is a vector of probabilities that sum to one, so the closest I could think of was a PMF.

That helps, but "output of a model" doesn't describe the mechanism used to obtain these probabilities.  They look like fractions (of common denominator a multiple of 10).  One essential part of analyzing and answering your question well concerns how those probabilities might vary.  If there is no mechanism of variation -- if, for instance, the models would always output these probabilities no matter what -- then the question of "significantly different" is meaningless: the vectors are different, period.  So: please be more specific about this mechanism.

The vectors vary with each $x_i$. Each model is a function generating the vectors. For example, the model $f$ may output $[0,0,1]$ for $x_0$ if the model has learned that $x_0$ belongs to class $c_2$ (corresponding to the 1 in the output vector), but model $g$ may output $[0.5, 0.5, 0]$ for the same $x_0$ if this model learned that $x_0$ belongs to class $c_0$ or class $c_1$. The models learn by fitting their parameters on a training set. How the models exactly produce the vectors given $x_i$'s is unclear.
Note, I do not want to compare the vectors, but the functions $f$ and $g$.

What is the randomness involved here? The models output different vectors, so why wouldn't they be different? Randomness would be when you measure those vectors with additional noise, or when those vectors describe a population, and you wish to compare the population distributions.

The models change their output based on how they are defined. For example, model $f$ is defined as $f(x) = max(xW, 0)$ where W are the model parameters, while model $g$ is defined as $g(x) = max(max(xW_0, 0)W_1, 0)$. Now the question is did this change in the model definition make a difference or not?
The difficulty comes from the randomness in the process, so two identical models, will have different model parameters given the random seed that was used when fitting the model parameters as they are fit via stochastic gradient descent.

So, training the same model but with different random seeds will give multiple models, each with slightly different output. The pair-wise differences between these different outputs can serve as a null distribution. Then, we can compare this null distribution with the distribution of the differences between the two models we are interested in comparing. Assume the two distributions are Gaussian, and do a simple Z-test. Is this valid and is there a better approach?

Outputs that are the direct results of non-differentiable functions (like $\max$) of random variables often are not remotely Gaussian, casting doubt on whether your proposal is valid.

Assuming the distributions of the differences is Gaussian, not the distribution of the output vectors. The differences are calculated with JS-divergence which is a differentiable function and I vaguely remember that they were in fact Gaussian. I will run some experiments to test for normality and get back with the results.
But I agree with you in principle, hence the need to find a better approach.

You should really consider resampling your test/train set in addition to having different seeds ...

If you look into bootstrap tests, I guess you will find the idea of a null (bootstrap) distribution of a sampling statistic (in your case the JS statistic of your different PMF generating models) and comparison to the zero value. But the question to me really is: it does not matter if g and f give different output ("internal metric" within the models f and g), it matters if the output agrees with your ground truth (external metric looking at ground truth). An external metric could be the cross entropy loss. I would then rather look at the bootstrap distributions of this loss for both models.

Thank you for your comments. They are all good suggestions and the current common practice. However, I aim to do something different, in addition to what you suggest, for the following reasons. Resampling the test/train is a source of bias (different test splits causes the model to behave differently) and I do not regard it as a proper null distribution (difference only due to chance).  Also, it is common that resampling the test/train sets is not practical due to the size of the sets or in the case of time series, future data leakage.

Regarding your comment about internal vs external metric, I wish to compare the outputs of the models directly because the metrics, if calculated over the whole test set, are just averages. So two models may have exactly the same test set loss or error but in fact behave very differently if the specific test samples they make the errors on are different. If the loss is not calculated on the whole test set, but per test sample, then it is the same as if we would have used the model outputs directly, i.e. the internal metric.

During resampling you need to make sure that you do not introduce leakage. This is easily done by e.g. block bootstrap where you resample all related time series together   etc. Instead of computing the cross entropy loss you could also build histograms of the weighted log likelihoods... This is certainly not equivalent to only comparing the model outputs of f and g, because the ground truth weighting factor is missing. So just by looking at the internal comparison you can only know if the models agree with each other, but you cannot know if they agree with the ground truth

The randomness introduced by Bootstrapping is "true" in the sense that you draw samples from the empirical distribution function. You can read on the "bootstrap world", if you want a nice interpretation of this

Exactly, I wish to only know if the models agree with each other. It is a separate problem to assess them with the ground truth (if known) and to say which model is preferred. I am trying to develop a method for general model comparison during model development. I want to answer the question "Did it make a difference that I modified the model in some way or not?".

Thank you for the bootstrap world, I will read through. But, I do not want to use bootstraping the test/train set to generate null distributions because an outlier in the test/train set can cause the model difference to be unnecessarily large.

Even with the edits, the question is too complicated to get at once. With the edits it has even only become more complex. Describe everything in simpler words from the beginning and don't expect that readers, if they got through the first half, might still be interested in that edit. Remember, as of now this post has only 170 views, it is important to catch as much attention as you want and you can not rely on a random viewer understanding your vague story.

In your original post, essentially, you are comparing pairs for each $x_i$: $F(x_i), G(x_i)$ the distribution functions of the PMFs $g(x_i),  f(x_i)$. Now the question is what you are interested in, when comparing. While I do not know this, I can imagine that you are looking for some "stochastic ordering". Many times stochastic dominance of 0,1,2,3 order is of interest ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance
Now you would still have the problem how to aggregate over the different x_i and how a binary outcome like "g(x_i) dominates f(x_i) stochastically ->yes=1/no=0" shall be aggregated (counting, averaging, median... ) - all not obvious
However, if you want to compare model performance in some metric, I would not pair by the random seeds (since it is absolutely random what happens with one model and another one with more parameters ... So that variance reduction by using common random number is senseless in my opinion). Now ignoring the seeds and rather training the two types of models repeatedly (on [grouped] bootstrap training/test datasets + different random seeds) you get two distributions of model performances. Now you can look at the median, mean of the model performances or do a model elaborate comparison of models by looking at different stochastic dominances (e.g. first order stochastic dominance which compares all quantiles at once (not only the median)...)
You can also test for stochastic dominance then with specific hypothesis tests, but (approximate) first order stochastic dominance shall be evident in the empirical cumulative distribution functions with point wise error bars. If one model dominates the other one you shall see a plot like the one in wikipedia. I say approximate because you do not know and cannot know the true underlying distribution function of the model performances of your models ... So using the empirical distribution functions as a drop in replacement serves as an approximation which (hopefully) becomes valid in the limit of infinite bootstrapped test/train runs. Maybe someone with more rigor can add a nice explanation here.

Thank you for bringing to my attention the notion of stochastic dominance, I was not aware of it. However, it does not apply to my case. Stochastic dominance means one set of probabilities always produce a more desirable outcome than another set of probabilities. In my case, the probabilities are just estimate of some distribution and there is no desirable outcome. To be clear, I did not say nor intend to pair by random seeds. The rest of your answer I address in the question comments.


How to test whether f and g are significantly different from each other?

There is a difference between statistical significance and practical significance. Your sample size is as large as you want given that you can just rerun $f, g$ with new seeds, so statistical significance is basically guaranteed. You need to find some practical criterion. Ggjj11s answer sounds like a good recommendation. Also with regards to not fixing random seeds.
If you want to stick with JS-Divergence I'd simply plot the distributions of
$$
\begin{aligned} 
D_f(x_i) &= d(f(x_i), f(x_i)) \\
D_g(x_i) &= d(g(x_i), g(x_i)) \\
D(x_i) &=  d(f(x_i), g(x_i))
\end{aligned}
$$
with $f(x_i), g(x_i)$    being random variables due to non fixed seed. Now there are two questions:

Do $D_f$ and $D_g$ look similar?
If yes, does $D$ also fit?

If $f, g$ behave very differently, then you will probably see that in question 1. To implement this I'd iterate over $x$ and calculate two values of $f, g$ each, giving me 1 value of $D_f$ and $D_g$ each and (at least, but I don't want to reuse values) 2 values of $D$. Here is  a toy implementation in R, with slightly different $f, g$:
JS <- function(p, q){
  n <- 0.5 * (p + q)
  0.5 * (sum(p * log(p / n)) + sum(q * log(q / n)))
}
dim_PMF <- 100
# I don't use x, but it's there...
f_fun <- function(x_i){
    y <- runif(dim_PMF)
    return(y/sum(y))
}

g_fun <- function(x_i){
  y <- plogis(rnorm(dim_PMF)))
  return(y/sum(y))
}

n_x <- 10000
x <- rnorm(n_x)
eval_at_x <- function(x){
  f1 <- f_fun(x)
  f2 <- f_fun(x)
  g1 <- g_fun(x)
  g2 <- g_fun(x)
  return(c(Df = JS(f1, f2), Dg = JS(g1, g2), D1 = JS(f1, g1), D2 = JS(f2, g2)))
}

res <- t(vapply(x, eval_at_x, FUN.VALUE = c(1, 2,3 ,4)))
summary(res)

my_lims <- range(res)
my_breaks <- seq(my_lims[1], my_lims[2], length.out = 100)


hist(res[,1], xlim = my_lims, breaks = my_breaks, col = rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.5), 
     ylim = c(0, 600), main = "JS of the 3 pairings", xlab = "JS")
hist(res[,2], xlim = my_lims, breaks = my_breaks, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha = 0.5), add = T)
legend("topright",legend = c("D", "Df", "Dg"), 
       fill = c(rgb(0, 1, 0, alpha = 0.5), rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.5), rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha = 0.5)))

hist(res[,3], xlim = my_lims, breaks = my_breaks, col = rgb(0, 1, 0, alpha = 0.3), add = T)
hist(res[,4], xlim = my_lims, breaks = my_breaks, col = rgb(0, 1, 0, alpha = 0.3), add = T)

Question 1): clearly different

Question 2): $D$ is very much in the middle


Thank you for your answer. I awarded the bounty to this answer as it is closest to what the question is asking, although is not providing a full answer. I guess I underestimated the complexity of the problem. I did as your answer suggest, however, the distributions do not look nice like the example you showed. There are usually just two big peaks. One at zero, because for many $x_i$ the model outputs are essentially the same, and one at some number which is the JS when the model outputs differ at one vector element for many $x_i$. So, comparing these distributions is difficult.
